# How to hide panel with animation.css sliding effects in gwt.?

Tags: java, html, css, animation, gwt

I have created a panel in gwt like,

```
        VerticalPanel myPanel = new VerticalPanel();
```

then I have applied animation css to myPanel for sliding effects while hiding a panel like,

```
myPanel.addStyleName("animated slideInRight");
myPanel.setVisible(false);
```

the above code hides the myPanel before slideInRight effect is shown.? Why is it so i.e. myPanel doesn't slide as per css before hide.?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setVisible(false)` it is executed immediately - it does not wait for the animation to finish.

You need to delay this line until the animation ends by using a Timer:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         myPanel.setVisible(false);
     }
 };
 timer.schedule(500);
```

Set the delay to match your animation time.